# How to convert Date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change date format sequence from yy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yy

How can I do it in Javascript ?

I have tried

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("mm-dd-yy");
```

But its not working for me

Comment: if you want `dd-mm-yy`, then why does your code say `mm-dd-yy`?

Comment: Do you already have a date in yy-mm-dd format or are you trying to do it for now?

Comment: Not so hard to check on internet... http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

Comment: Out of curiosity, what let you to think that Date objects had a format function?   You can easily look up a list of functions that are available to the object...  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @Tim Just imagine I have used a date with format mm-dd-yy in 100 places, but it want same date in dd-mm-yy format in one place. Thats why

Comment: Ok. I asked because you'd be surprised how many people post code here without really reading or understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clear and simple approach

```
var now = new Date();     
var dd = now.getDate();    //returns date
var mm = now.getMonth()+ 1; //returns month and you need to add1 because it is array
var yy = now.getFullYear(); //returns full year 
var st = dd + '-' + mm  + "-" + yy;  //format as string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateFormatted = (now.getMonth()+1)+"-"+now.getDate()+"-"+now.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned function to format Date

```
utilities.FormatDate(new Date(),"GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: ...if you use Google Apps, that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dateformat(date)
{
  var yourdate = new Date(date);
 yourdate = yourdate.getDate() + '-' + yourdate.getMonth() +1 + "-"  +yourdate.getFullYear();
}
```

use - or / as you like